# initialize event actions to raise event notifications

Tags: c#

I would like to create event actions to notify other classes when something happened. So my current flow looks like this

[image]

For testing purposes I created this code

**Program.cs**

Instantiate the first class and call a method from it (constructor is fine).

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        First f = new First();
    }
}
```

**First.cs**

Instantiate the second class and call a method from it (constructor is fine). Listen for an event of the second class when some data has changed.

```
internal class First
{
    public First()
    {
        // ...

        Second s = new Second();
        s.Updated += OnSecondUpdated;
    }

    private void OnSecondUpdated()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Second.cs**

Instantiate the third class and call a method from it (constructor is fine). Listen for an event of the third class when some data has changed and raise the own one.

```
internal class Second
{
    public event Action Updated;

    public Second()
    {
        // ...

        Third t = new Third();
        t.Updated += OnThirdUpdated;
    }

    private void OnThirdUpdated()
    {
        // ...

        Updated();
    }
}
```

**Third.cs**
Raise an event when some data has changed.

```
internal class Third
{
    public event Action Updated;

    public Third()
    {
        // ...

        Updated();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the event variables are null. How can I instantiate these variables properly?

Comment: Take a look at the *observer* design pattern.

Comment: thank you very much but is it possible to fix the current code? I think there is a syntax problem but I didn't get it ..

Comment: You are first executing `Update()` and then linking the events because the logic is inside each constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to do this in the constructor, where at that time nothing has (yet) been assigned to the `Updated` event. You can "solve" this by checking for null:

```
internal class Third
{
    public event Action Updated;

    public Third()
    {
        // ...
        if(Updated != null)
            Updated();
    }
}
```

But it wont mean your code now "works" as you only assign the event a handler *after* constructor has been called:

```
Third t = new Third();
t.Updated += OnThirdUpdated;
```

So one possible solution for this pattern is to NOT do this raising of the event in the constructor, and instead defer the logic to another method.

```
internal class Third
{
    public event Action Updated;

    public Third()
    {            
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        // ...
        if(Updated != null)
            Updated();
    }
}

Third t = new Third();
t.Updated += OnThirdUpdated;
t.Init();
```

Answer (score 1):

You call the `Update()` before the classes can subscribe to the events, due to the constructor of the underlying object being called first. I changed it so that the constructor takes the related class and subscribes the event itself.

```
internal class First
{
    public First()
    {
        Second s = new Second(this);
    }

    internal void OnSecondUpdated()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

internal class Second
{
    public event Action Updated;

    public Second(First f)
    {
        Updated += f.OnSecondUpdated;
        Third t = new Third(this);
    }

    internal void OnThirdUpdated()
    {
        Updated();
    }
}

internal class Third
{
    public event Action Updated;

    public Third(Second s)
    {
        Updated += s.OnThirdUpdated;
        Updated();
    }
}
```